# Selecting last row WITHOUT any kind of key

Tags: mysql

I need to get the last (newest) row in a table (using MySQL's natural order - i.e. what I get without any kind of ORDER BY clause), however there is no key I can ORDER BY on!

The only 'key' in the table is an indexed MD5 field, so I can't really ORDER BY on that. There's no timestamp, autoincrement value, or any other field that I could easily ORDER on either. This is why I'm left with only the natural sort order as my indicator of 'newest'.

And, unfortunately, changing the table structure to add a proper auto_increment is out of the question. :(

Anyone have any ideas on how this can be done w/ plain SQL, or am I SOL?

Comment: The hideously inefficient method would be to just fetch all records and discard all but the last one. Other than that, can't think of anything that would work without a key/date field.

Comment: I would think that there generally one would take no assumptions about the order of the records returned without explicitely specifying one? Is there such a thing as *natural order*?

Comment: There appears to be "natural" order with MyISAM tables if you never delete any rows, though I've never sen that guaranteed, and wouldn't rely on it. It'd be far less troublesome to redesign the table.

Comment: @nos: thanks, this is the first time i've heard about guarantueed order from any database without specifying one. I think *not* relying on that would be sound advice indeed...

Comment: You're in a bit of a pickle, I'd say.

Answer (score 3):

If it's MyISAM you can do it in two queries

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable;  
SELECT * FROM yourTable LIMIT useTheCountHere - 1,1;
```

This is unreliable however because

1. It assumes rows are only added to this table and never deleted.
2. It assumes no other writes are performed to this table in the meantime (you can lock the table)
3. MyISAM tables can be reordered using ALTER TABLE, so taht the insert order is no longer preserved.

It's not reliable at all in InnoDB, since this engine can reorder the table at will.

Comment: Got a syntax error because of the 'useTheCountHere - 1' part, not sure why. Inputting the actual result offset worked, e.g. in PHP: ..."LIMIT ".count - 1.",1"...

Answer (score 1):

Can I ask why you need to do this?

In oracle, possibly the same for MySQL too but the optimiser will choose the quickest record / order to return you results. So there is potential if your data was static to run the same query twice and get a different answer.

Comment: I did not know that, then it would be pointless to get all the rows and grab the last one...

Comment: Well as I said my comment is Oracle related. Is there no way you can add a timestamp column to the table?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign row numbers using the [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) function and then sort by this value using the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS rn  
FROM table 
ORDER BY rn DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't do that.

Normally I'd suggest adding a surrogate primary key with auto-incrememt and ORDER BY that:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But in your question you write...

> changing the table structure to add a proper auto_increment is out of the question.

So another less pleasant option I can think of is using a simulated ROW_NUMBER using variables:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT T1.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rn
    FROM yourtable T1, (SELECT @rownum := 0) T2
) T3
ORDER BY rn DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Please note that this has serious performance implications: it requires a full scan and the results are not guaranteed to be returned in any particular order in the subquery - you *might* get them in sort order, but then again you might not - when you dont' specify the order the server is free to choose any order it likes. Now it *probably* will choose the order they are stored on disk in order to do as little work as possible, but relying on this is unwise.

Comment: And also assumes that rows are returned in insert order, which is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 0):

Without an `order by` clause you have no guarantee of the order in which you will get your result. The SQL engine is free to choose any order.

But if for some reason you still want to rely on this order, then the following will indeed return the last record from the result (MySql only):

```
select *
from   (select *,
               @rn := @rn + 1 rn
        from   mytable,
               (select @rn := 0) init        
       ) numbered
where  rn = @rn
```

In the sub query the records are retrieved without `order by`, and are given a sequential number. The outer query then selects only the one that got the last attributed number.

Answer (score -3):

We can use the having for that kind of problem-

```
SELECT MAX(id) as last_id,column1,column2 FROM table HAVING id=last_id;
```