# Retrieving latest Record in to the table

Tags: postgresql

I have one table `temp(sid integer, sname varchar, adress varchar)`

This table contains 10 records I need to retrieve latest insert records

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

A simple select statement should do it

```
SELECT * from temp 
ORDER BY sid DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: sid column doesnt have primary key

Comment: Is the sid incremental? If you do not have an incremental value or some kind of datetime field, then unfortunately there is no way of really knowing which is the latest record. Alternatively you can get everything from the table and just take the last row using php or something as normally there is a natural order to tables, however, there is absolutely no guarantee with this method. Please see this post for a similar request

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631060/selecting-last-row-without-any-kind-of-key